# Insert query is run successfully, but the data is not inserted into the database (C#)

Tags: c#, oledb

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(check.Properties.Settings.Default.KitchenConnectionString);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter items = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("insert into Sets(SetId, SetName,  SetPassword) values('"+txt_id.Text+ "','" + txt_setname.Text + "','" + txt_password.Text + "');", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        command.ExecuteReader();

        connection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Inserted!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the connectionstring used?

Comment: Please read http://Bobby-tables.com - you need to level up your SQL skills, and never again write an SQL like you do here; we've fired developers for doing it because it's that much of a [hacking risk](https://coar.risc.anl.gov/consequences-of-sql-injection-attacks/)

Comment: Also, jps' now-deleted answer makes a valid point: use ExecuteReader only for queries that return data. Use ExecuteNonQuery for queries that don't

Comment: `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Comment: @Steve OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.KitchenConnectionString);

Comment: @CaiusJard I use ExecuteNonQuery() also but data is not saving permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that it's Ole, I'm guessing this is Access - a file based database. Your insert is running successfully but you don't find the data in the db when you look

You need to appreciate that typically withba probe t that uses an access db you will have several copies of the db but the most relevant ones are probably like:

```
C:\myprojects\windowsapp1\your.accdb 
C:\myprojects\windowsapp1\bin\debug\your.accdb
```

The first one is the db you see in the solution explorer. The second one is placed next to your debug exe every time you run a build, or possibly every time you click play in VS. The second one is probably the db your program is inserting into

You're either looking in the wrong db for your data, or every time you run your program the build process erases the changes db by copying the empty one (first one) over the top of it.

Run your app, insert your data, don't quit your app, Search your entire project folder for all instances of your db file. Look in all of them. You'll probably find your data

- Right click the db file in solution explorer, choose properties, and change the Copy action to Copy If Newer

Now the build process will only erase your db in the debug folder if you make a change to the source db, eg add a table to it etc

Comment: I enter data and don't quit the app and search for that data in both DB files but i can't find entered data.

Comment: Post the actual value of your connection string setting (project menu, properties, settings)

Comment: Ok ok i got the value and please tell me how to change copy action. ❤️

Comment: I put a dot next to the advice you need, at the bottom of my answer

Comment: I did same but in properties panel i found just "provider", "state", "type", "version", "connection string" values. But can't find "Copy Action" option. I am using VS 2015.

Comment: I was gonna say, are you sure you right clicked the database file in solution explorer? It seems you might have got properties on a database connection in the Server Explorer judging by the names of those props :) - is day to make sure it's Solution explorer and you can see all the code files of the project, and data files like the accdb file. Also usually solution explorer is on the right, server explorer is normally on the left

Comment: Actually in first try i was trying to get properties of database which was located on left side. After that, i open properties of database on solution explorer that was located on right side. My issue resolved.

Comment: But now when i try to delete data, it is not deleting from database. I try to delete data from datagridview and database simultaneously.

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.category_grid.SelectedRows)
                {
                    string name = item.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("delete  from Category where CatName = '" +name+ "'",connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    category_grid.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                    connection.Close();
                }

Comment: If you have "a database on the left side" then you're actually just a couple of mouse clicks away from being able to do all this automatically; Visual Studio will write the code for you that does all this..

Comment: I have database on left side and i have done copy action to "copy if newer" but now delete query is not performing action :(

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns an int. if it returns 1, 1 row was deleted, and you're looking in the wrong database. If it returns 0, no row was deleted